# Twitter bootstrap: how to hide Tabbable tab header?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Totally a web newbie here. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to build my personal website.
I like the Tabbable, which content can be switched without refreshing the page. However, I don't want to show the tab header, instead, I want to use the NavBar to act as the header.
Is there any way to hide the header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.hide` class on the tab header that you want to hide, or just remove the tab list item all together:

```
<ul class="nav hide nav-tabs" id="tab">
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Another question, do you know how to show the tab content by using teh navbar? I set the navbar's href to the id but it doesn't work.

Comment: @AZ Are you also supplying the `data-toggle` attribute to your nav menu items?  Without it it won't work: `<a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>`